# get parameter from url and save the parameter in other links on the same page

Tags: javascript, url, asp-classic

I have a problem and i need some help please. I have this page with a parameter http://www.webxpress.com/landingpage.asp?label=CSU... 
Now in this page i have 3 buttons with the following links:
www.webxpress.com/button1.asp
www.webxpress.com/button2.asp
www.webxpress.com/button3.asp

All i want is to add the parameter in the button links (depending on the parameter in the url)... For example: from www.webxpress.com/button1.asp the link comes www.webxpress.com/button1.asp?label=CSU (this parameter is taken from the url).

Can someone please help me and give me some tips because i do not know from where i should start.

Comment: Are you wanting to get the parameter using Javascript or with ASP?

Comment: both are fine.The only important thing is that it works...

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

> document.location.search

which returns the part of the URL after the ? sign (including the question-mark).

To test that this is what you want, try to navigate with your browser on a page with such parameters, and then type in the address bar of the browser:

> javascript:alert(document.location.search)

Then, you can use document.write to write the links with this value at the end:

> document.write("<a href='http://.../button1.asp" + document.location.search + "'>button1 link</a>");

Comment: Thanks for this though i have a problem...my link already contains 2 parameters and the result i am having is the following http://www.webxpress.com/landingpage.asp?label=CSU&tyt=345?label=CSU.... I am having 2 questions marks...I need to put & instead of ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `document.location.search` as the previous comment suggested and extract the part you are interested in. Afterwards you can iterate over every link in the page with `document.links` and update them.

For example:

```
dl = document.links;
for(i = 0, len = dl.length; i < len; i++) {
  dl[i].href = dl[i].href + '&label=CSU";
}
```

Comment: Good idea, though i want this to be dynamic... the parameter in the url is not going to be the same... It changes from now and then...

Comment: Well you can update that in the JavaScript code from your server side script, no?